# Abrir JFileChooser com campo "Nome do Arquivo" preenchido

Tags: java

Como posso abrir o JFileChooser com o campo "Nome do Arquivo" preenchido?

Este campo da imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem do campo que quero abrir preenchido com algum nome]

Como setar um nome para abrir como padrão neste campo?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema com a resposta postada?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar o método `setSelectedFile`

```
JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
jFileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("fileToSave.txt"));
jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(parent);
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name)